# How to work around the PFX signing not supported error when publishing .NET Core

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, certificate, publish, pfx

I've been trying to sign assemblies with a PFX file. All worked fine, I accessed Properties/Signing at Visual Studio yet whenever I run the *dotnet publish* command, I get this error:

*C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3210,5): error PFX signing not supported on .NET Core*

I've been looking for a way to work around this, yet with no luck so far.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6911

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I figured I should go with SNK signing instead of PFX, considering it's no longer supported by PFX.

Answer (score 1):

1. Export public key from the PFX: `sn -p key.pfx key.pub`
2. Enable delayed signing for your assembly by adding `<DelaySign>true</DelaySign>` to the project file or by `AssemblyDelaySignAttribute`. Use a public key from step 1 instead of the PFX for signing.
3. Re-sign your assembly after build: `sn -R assembly.dll key.pfx`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sn-exe-strong-name-tool