# dotnet build command in a batch build with strong name signed projects

Tags: .net, batch-file, command-line-interface

I have a solution with several publishing profiles. when inside VisualStudio 2019, I Righ-Click the project, select Publish, select the profile and publish all works like a charm when I do the same from a cmd line I get an error.

My command is:

```
dotnet build "D:\Source\project name\DllName.csproj" /p:PublishProfile=Release
```

The error I get is

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-rc.2.20479.15\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3242,5): error : PFX signing not supported on .NET Core

I have a normal pfx signature on my project, not sure what the issue is, what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to work around the PFX signing not supported error when publishing .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105698/how-to-work-around-the-pfx-signing-not-supported-error-when-publishing-net-core)

Comment: @SomethingDark, not really, I think that there must be a way to use the default infrastructure and ecosystem in visual studio to publish a project using the command-line interface being PowerShell or batch. will be hard to sell removing password security from the certificates as anyone can start signing in our name....

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/master/src/Tasks/ResolveKeySource.cs#L157 - I would open an issue in that repo asking why this is.